# How to find the CDF and PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

How to find the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) and Probability Distribution Function (PDF) for uniform variable inside circle given by $R^2 = (X-c_1)^2+(Y-c_2)^2$, where ($c_1, c_2$) is the center of circle.

I think that the PDF for problem is given by

\begin{equation}
f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\pi R^2}&, \quad (x-c_1)^2 + (y-c_2)^2 \leq R^2\\
0&, \quad otherwise
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Comment: What is the variable?

Comment: Sorry, the variable is $T = \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$

Comment: What is CDF, PDF?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: That doesn't help us unless you tell us what the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ are.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are uniform distribution in ($a,b$).

Comment: @WagnerJorge Put that in the opening post. $\uparrow$

Comment: The OP completed the problem in the comments to my answer, please reopen the question...

Comment: I modified the question. When will reopen it?

Comment: I edited and I modified the question, but still it was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**
$$
\begin{split}
F_T(t) &= \mathbb{P}[T < t] \\
       &= \mathbb{P}\left[X^2 + Y^2 < t^2\right] \\
       &= \frac{1}{(b-a)^2} \int_a^b \int_a^b \mathbb{I}_{x^2 + y^2 < t^2}dxdy
\end{split}
$$
and you can transform the integral over the indicator by integrating over the correct region...

Comment: Applying polar coordinates the integral above is given by $F_T(t) = \frac{1}{(b-a)^2}\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{2\pi}rd\theta dr$, then the cumulative distribution function is $F_T(t) = \frac{\pi t^2}{(b-a)^2}$. Correct?

Comment: @WagnerJorge exactly.