# How to find CDF on disk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $Z = (X, Y)$ be a random variable uniform inside circle of radius $R$. How to find cumulative distribution function (CDF) on disk?

Comment: Self-duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1931107/ Please stop that.

Comment: I reopened because the question was closed and I modified completely,but don't reopened.

Comment: Yes, and this is called cheating the system, so: *Please stop*.

Comment: I don't had knowledge, sorry. Please delete the question. I don't have the intention of to use cheat of system. I repeat I don't had knowledge. You can delete this question. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

See the figure below:

[image]

By the definition of the uniform distribution the CDF can be calculated as follows:

$$P(X<x,Y<y)=\frac{\text{red area(x,y)}}{R^2\pi}$$